# How to add command line options to script downloaded using curl

Tags: bash, curl, arguments, process-substitution

I have the following in my CI script . . .

```
- bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash -gtest)
```

What is the correct syntax to ge the `-g` bit working?

Of course

```
- curl -s https://codecov.io/bash >> codecov
- chmod +x codecov
- ./codecov -gtest
```

.. but can it be done without making a local file out of interest??

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't suggest passing [output from curl directly to bash](https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2016/04/detecting-curl-pipe-bash-server-side/), but have you tried:

```
bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash) -gtest
```

Test:

```
% bash <(echo 'echo "$@"') -gtest and more
-gtest and more
```